# Httpclient connecting to https SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, dotnet-httpclient

I am successfully connecting to API in postman: 
GET on https:// 
with basic authorization (it creates appropriate header)

i use it in "interceptor mode" to get it working. When i do that, i see extra line in fiddler:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'd like to do the same thing in c# using http client and i have recreated same request, but it doesn't work. In fiddler i see additional item which says:

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
```

How can i get this working? It is trusted server.

Comment: Is the certificate used on the server trusted? Or do you have to accept the certificate in Chrome when running from Postman?

Comment: in the end, i figured that creator of api made a mistake. it didn't give me a clear message that i am unauthorized because of bad authorisation code he gave me. :(